# Is Any Difference in Session["value"] and Session["VALUE"]?

Tags: asp.net, session

I am bit confusing between these session variable `Session["value"]` and `Session["VALUE"]`

OR
**Is Session's Value Is Case-Sensitive or not?**

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The value is not case sensitive, so `Session["value"]` and `Session["VALUE"]` are both the same thing.